# How to change clay color in Bukkit

Tags: java, bukkit

Hi I'm trying to change the color of clay within an inventory in Bukkit for my Minecraft server but I can't figure out how to do this. The code I have doesn't work. All it does it set the item in the inventory with the proper name and lore but doesn't actually change the color of the clay block.

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static ItemStack[] achievements(Player player){
    ItemStack[] items = new ItemStack[54];
    for(int i = 1; i <= MySQL.getAmountOfAchievements(); i++){
        ItemStack clay = new ItemStack(Material.STAINED_CLAY);

        if(MySQL.hasAchievement(player, i)){
            clay.setData(new MaterialData((byte) 5));
        }else{
            clay.setData(new MaterialData((byte) 14));
        }

        ItemMeta clayMeta = clay.getItemMeta();
        clayMeta.setDisplayName(MySQL.getAchievementName(i));
        List<String> description = new ArrayList<String>();
        description.add(MySQL.getAchievementDescription(i));
        clayMeta.setLore(description);

        clay.setItemMeta(clayMeta);

        items[i - 1] = clay;
    }

    return items;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `setData(MaterialData)`, you should use `setDurability(short)`.

In place of `clay.setData(new MaterialData((byte) 5))`, you could use `clay.setDurability(5)`, and in place of `clay.setData(new MaterialData((byte) 14))`, you could use `clay.setDurability(14)`.

Here's what your code could look like:

```
if(MySQL.hasAchievement(player, i)){
  clay.setDurability(5);
}
else{
  clay.setDurability(14);
}
```

Using `.setDurability(short)` sets the data of the item (for example, in `clay:5`, the data would be `5`). It is called `setDurability` because the data also sets the durability of tools such as swords and pickaxes.